# how do I schedule a azure VM to shutdown on weekends and start it on weekdays in resource manager

Tags: powershell, azure, scheduled-tasks, azure-automation

**Need to schedule power off/ on the  VM's runnning in resource manager to avoid charges?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scheduled task in Azure Automation to do that. An example of a workflow to start/stop ARM VMs is here:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ShutdownStart-ARM-VMs-by-3435f3a0

Comment: Thanks Neil, I have scheduled it trough Automaiton and its working fine. :)